# PWA - Android, iOS, MacOS, Windows Store, Chrome Add to Home Screen - Problems with multi tenancy app with multi domains

Tags: android, ios, macos, windows-store-apps, progressive-web-apps

I have couple questions about generating `PWA App`. Maybe at the first step I explain something about app for better understanding my problems with generating app for multiplatforms.

#### Multi Tenancy App

I can't say much more about application. This is application where users can create own account. Accounts is separated at servers, eg. app1, app2, app3 etc. Every server has his own domain, eg. `app1.example.com` etc. Every user can upgrade his account to premium type and define own domain, which can be go on and login to his account without using global domains (here is a problem with PWA app, multi domains). I think it is everything what you need to know, if you need more specific info, give me a feedback, I will try to help you. I need to use `WebView` because app need access to `localStorage`.

#### My problems

1. Problem is with multi domains. In `manifest.json` configuration is possible to define one domain, which app will be use to display application and authorize it (with `assetlinks.json`) to don't display URL Bar (for `"Add to Home Screen"` - with `android` app is possible to add wildcard).
2. I need possibility to use application with multi domains (I achieve it on `android` - explanation in the following part of post).
3. Problem is too with adding application from mobile Chrome `"Add to Home Screen"` and on the desktop `"Install app..."`. After redirect to other URL, URL Bar is shown.
4. Next problem is to compile `Windows Store app` from `Visual Studio` (explanation in the following part of post).
5. I need more info about compiling app for `iOS` and `MacOS` - is this possible to compile and test it without `Apple` devices? I tried to use `pwabuilder.com`, but after download `MacOS` package folder is empty. Maybe virtual machine could help me with that? What you recommend too use to make that application? I tested what I found in `google`, but it wasn't what I expect.

#### Installation from `Chrome` browser

Is possible to change user URL without showing URL Bar? Now after autorization user and redirect him on the properly his premium address url bar is showing - i don't want users to have to go on properly domain and install app from `"Add to Home Screen"` - they should install it from any domain and use it like `Native App`.

#### `Android`

Partially solved problem with subdomains for every account. It's working properly, but maybe someone has any other authorization solution where I don't need custom subdomain for authorize app.

#### `Windows Store`

I installed `Visual Studio`, make new application with this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps/windows-features) but I getting error

> Error Project must have a reference to an application. Please add a reference under the 'Applications' node in the Solution Explorer.

Here is an [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/edge-developer/issues/273) - Maybe problem is with newest version of Visual Studio? Next question is, even if I compile the App, what with multi domain - URL Bar will be visible when user will be redirected? What if Chrome don't be installed?

#### `iOS` and `MacOS`

Maybe someone has good documentation how to create apps on this platform and where can I test it? What with multi domain? URL Bar will be shown? Is possible to make it invisible like an `Android App` eg. `wildcard` or other solution?

#### My questions

1. How to create `PWA` app for `iOS` and `MacOS`. Maybe is nice documentation for it.
2. How to build application for `Windows Store`. I made app with Microsoft documentation, but it doesn't work - problem was open on `GitHub Issue`, but without solution.
3. Is possible to use multi domains and don't show URL Bar for applications installed from mobile Chrome like a `"Add to Home"` or desktop Chrome `"Install app..."`.
4. What if `Chrome` don't be installed on device? Application will be working properly? I know from `android 8.1` is possible to remove `chrome` from `android`. I don't know if after remove `Chrome application` will be working?

**Thanks everyone for help and your patience, I counting on much help from you.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm recently building a PWA with Vue and I'm trying to find a way of making the IOS package out of It. So far I haven't done yet but for Windows, Android & MacOs are pretty easy ... There a lot of blog tutorials for that and if you don't want to go through much of coding then the [PWA Builder](https://www.pwabuilder.com/serviceworker) is the best option for you.

For your 4th question if you want to run a PWA from a browser the browser you have must support standalone desktop apps.
I wanted to try my PWA on iPhone from Chrome and couldn't because that chrome does not have the feature to pin an app to screen so I had to rely on safari only